# Hazelcast client connection disconnection events triggered even if there is still one member node remaining

Tags: cluster-computing, hazelcast

I have 2 member nodes and 1 client that joins the cluster.

1. Member A is started on localhost 5701

```
    JoinConfig join = config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5701).getJoin();
    join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    join.getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
    join.getTcpIpConfig().addMember("localhost:5701").setEnabled(true);
    join.getTcpIpConfig().addMember("localhost:5702").setEnabled(true);
    HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

2. Member B is started on localhost 5702

```
    Config config = new Config();
    JoinConfig join = config.getNetworkConfig().setPort(5702).getJoin();
    join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    join.getAwsConfig().setEnabled(false);
    join.getTcpIpConfig().addMember("localhost:5701").setEnabled(true);
    join.getTcpIpConfig().addMember("localhost:5702").setEnabled(true);
    HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

3. Client joins on addresses:

```
  config = new ClientConfig();
   config.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("localhost:5701", "localhost:5702");
   instance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
```

4. Client adds a listener:

```
    instance.getLifecycleService().addLifecycleListener(new LifecycleListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(LifecycleEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("LIFECYCLE State changed: " + event);
                }
            });
```

5. Member A is bounced.
6. Client receives disconnection connection events:

```
  WARNING: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.7] Connection [/127.0.0.1:5701] lost. Reason: java.io.IOException[An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
  Sep 09, 2016 12:52:19 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
  INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.7] HazelcastClient 3.7 (20160817 - 1302600) is CLIENT_DISCONNECTED
  LIFECYCLE State changed: LifecycleEvent [state=CLIENT_DISCONNECTED]
  Sep 09, 2016 12:52:19 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientMembershipListener
  INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.7] 
  
  Members [2] {
      Member [localhost]:5701 - dc7a127d-8302-42f6-9e3e-82406162e245
      Member [localhost]:5702 - cb115830-bb71-4af2-a1c1-b11f39e351c8
  }
  
  Sep 09, 2016 12:52:19 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
  INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.7] HazelcastClient 3.7 (20160817 - 1302600) is CLIENT_CONNECTED
  LIFECYCLE State changed: LifecycleEvent [state=CLIENT_CONNECTED]
  Sep 09, 2016 12:52:24 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientMembershipListener
  INFO: hz.client_0 [dev] [3.7] 
  
  Members [1] {
      Member [localhost]:5702 - cb115830-bb71-4af2-a1c1-b11f39e351c8
  }
```

7. Now if I bounce Member A again, NO disconnect/connect events are received.
8. If I bounce Member B, I get the events again.

My question is why do I get these events even though at all times, at least one member is fully available? I would only expect these events only if the entire cluster is down (both members).

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about CLIENT_CONNECTED and CLIENT_DISCONNECTED events (LifecycleListener), right?

These are only delivered on connecting disconnecting to the cluster (i.e. only for connections which we call as the owner for that client). You do not receive events on reconnections to non-owner members.

Client connected to 5702 and when 5701 comes back, it will not try connect to 5701 as the owner since it already has an owner connection. Hence, no event will be received at step 7, which is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Yes, these events exactly. Ok, so the concept of "owner" connections - I didn't think a client connection would be associated with a specific member. The way I thought/hoped this worked was the client does not  see any events until the cluster was completely down (all members). Otherwise I think a client sees superfluous events -- when I put lifecycle handling code into the client, this is therefore getting invoked unecessarily.